# How to integrate cURL on my public_html?

Tags: command-line, ftp, php, curl, web-hosting

I do have this folder structure for my website:

```
\index.html
\php\some-php-files.php
\js\some-js-files.js
```

What I want to do is, I want to use a `cURL` command, which I usually use it on the terminal/CMD, to run it with one of my PHP file.

Usually my command line is like that `curl "https://example-website/test-video" --output test.mp4"`

**So my questions are:**

- Is it possible to integrate `cURL` to my website, to later call it with PHP?
- Which version of `cUR`L do I need to download? Its really the basic one, but how can identify which version of cURL does I need. My website is hosted by a webhoster, I do have the access on FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to integrate cURL to my website

There are two possible ways of "integrating" it:

1. Running the same `curl` shell command from PHP, through popen() or system(). This is not very efficient, and frankly outright dangerous if you intend to download URLs specified by random users. (Much like SQL, it *can* be done safely with escapeshellarg(), but that's a whole separate topic.)
2. Directly calling the *libcurl* core library that powers curl. This is the recommended method because PHP already has a [curl module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

(Note that PHP also has non-curl-based functions to download HTTP URLs, such as the ability to fopen() an URL and read it like a local file.)

> Which version of cURL do I need to download? Its really the basic one, but how can identify which version of cURL does I need. My website is hosted by a webhoster, I do have the access on FTP.

Ask your server administrator.

If you want to use the PHP curl module, you can't install it through FTP, so trying to download it yourself is likely a waste of time: the module has to be enabled in the global PHP settings by the webhoster anyway.

If you want to use the `curl` command (which you should reconsider), then you need to determine what OS the webhost is running, and whether you need a precompiled version or whether the webhost allows you to connect to a shell via SSH and compile the source code yourself. Although again it's better to ask the webhost administrator to just install it system-wide (which  they can do much faster, and in fact it might be *already* available).